# C# WCF Web API + JSONP

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, wcf-web-api

Is there an easy way to get JSONP working for the new WCF Web API rest services?

I've tried this with no luck

```
<standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint name=""
                      helpEnabled="true"
                      automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"
                      defaultOutgoingResponseFormat ="Json"
                      crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"/>
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/Look-Ma,-I-can-handle-JSONP-%28aka-Cross-Domain-JSON%29-with-WCF-Web-API-and-jQuery!/

Update:
Latest WCF Web API bits ships with integrated JSONP support whereas usage is almost similar to the way described in the link above.

Comment: Link has changed to: https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/Look-Ma,-I-can-handle-JSONP-%28aka-Cross-Domain-JSON%29-with-WCF-Web-API-and-jQuery!/

Comment: @ForOhFor Thanks for the reminder - updated the link

Answer (score 3):

You may checkout the [following blog post](http://bendewey.wordpress.com/2009/11/24/using-jsonp-with-wcf-and-jquery/) for using JSONP with WCF in .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to provide more detail on WCF WebAPI out-of-the-box support for JSONP.  I had a really hard time finding this information, so perhaps it will help somebody else...

[This thread](http://wcf.codeplex.com/discussions/281318) over on the WCF CodePlex has a description by Daniel Roth about how to use WebApi cross-domain JSON queries (a.k.a JSONP) using jQuery.

The "sample" he references can be found in the WCF CodePlex repository [here](http://wcf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets).  It is in the "default" folder.

Also, make sure you install the WebApiEnhancements for Preview 6 using NuGet otherwise none of this will work.

You'll need a Global.asax.cs with something like the following...

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        var config = new WebApiConfiguration() { EnableTestClient = true };
        RouteTable.Routes.MapServiceRoute<HelloWorldApi>("api", config);
    }
}
```

The other key is to account for an "extension" in your URI template...

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate="hello{ext}")]
```

Then you make your jQuery call like this...

```
$.getJSON("/api/hello.jsonp?callback=?", function (data) {
    $("div").html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's [another blog post](http://devtalk.net/dotnet/restful-web-conversations-3/) that describes how to add a `JsonpFormatter` to a project.