# WCF Web API preview 6: No 'MediaTypeFormatter' is available

Tags: wcf, wcf-web-api

I'm looking at using HttpClient in WCF Web API Preview 6 to consume a third party service.  This third party service accepts and returns XML formatted data.  Their HTTP responses have the Content-Type header set to text/plain.  It appears that having the response Content-Type set to text/plain is causing problems.  I'm making the request to the service as follows:

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> result = client.PostAsync(apiEndpoint, new ObjectContent(typeof (LeaveAccrualRequest), request));
```

Using Fiddler, I can see the request go to the service and an appropriate, expected response come back.  However when I try to access the response, I end up with the following InvalidOperationException:

*No 'MediaTypeFormatter' is available to read an object of type 'LeaveAccrualResponse' with the media type 'text/plain'.*

Is there a way to tell HttpClient that even though the HTTP response says the content type is text/plain, it should handle it as application/xml?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803264/c-sharp-wcf-web-api-jsonp/8990334#8990334)

Answer (score 1):

You could derive from XmlMediaTypeFormatter and add your "text/plain" header:

```
public class TextPlainXmlMediaTypeFormatter : XmlMediaTypeFormatter {
    public TextPlainXmlMediaTypeFormatter() {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain"));
    }
}
```

Depending on your requirements it could make sense to remove all other supported media types before adding "text/plain:

```
SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();
```

[Update]

Access your requests Content and use the ReadAsAsync<T> method overlaod which accepts an IEnumerable<MediaTypeFormatter>.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I added a derived class as you suggested and am now making my request like so:

            PlainTextXmlFormatter formatter = new PlainTextXmlFormatter();
            
            MediaTypeFormatterCollection formatters = new MediaTypeFormatterCollection{formatter};

            Task<HttpResponseMessage> result = client.PostAsync(apiEndpoint, new ObjectContent(typeof (LeaveAccrualRequest), request, formatters));

Still seeing the same error.  I've also tried removing all other supported media types but that didn't help

Comment: Sorry, my suggestion had been on server side. Updated my answer.