# How to call wcf web service from ajax?

Tags: c#, ajax, wcf

I need to call a wcf service from ajax. My web service Class is given bellow

```
public class AjaxService : IAjaxService
    {
        readonly Dictionary<string,int> _countryPostalCode = new Dictionary<string, int>
                                                        {
                                                            {"Bangladesh",1000},
                                                            {"India",2000},
                                                            {"Japan",3000}
                                                        };

        public int PostalCode(string countryName)
        {
            return _countryPostalCode[countryName];
        }
    }
```

How can I call it from ajax?? It will be very helpful for me if anyone explain it with example.

Comment: what did you already try?

Comment: I don't know the way to call a web service from client site that's why I asked

Comment: Why minus in this question?? Doesn't it follow the rule of stack overflow?

Comment: It  was not me, but probably because SO dies not suppose to be a Google ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First several results from google's query

> **calling wcf from ajax**

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128478/Consuming-WCF-REST-Services-Using-jQuery-AJAX-Call

[consuming wcf service application from JQuery Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684623/consuming-wcf-service-application-from-jquery-ajax)

http://www.yaplex.com/java-script/how-to-call-wcf-services-from-javascript-jquery-and-asp-net-ajax/

Comment: thanks a lot but I don't know why I got minus for this question.